# Spoofing CNAME in nslookup answer (DNS cloaking)

Tags: dns, cname, nslookup, cloaking

Is there a way to send custom reply to, for example, livejournal's nslookup request with custom CNAME answer?

Example:
livejournal sends nslookup request type CNAME to site.com;
site.com somehow answers only to livejournals request with "CNAME livejournal.com";
but other server tries to `nslookup` site.com with CNAME type of request and gets no "CNAME livejournal.com" answer.

I need this just like in example.

Please, help me if it possible at all %)

**UPD:** Okay. There is another question in context.
Livejournal takes tool to redirect blog to own domain: Write your domain name in form field in lj-blog settings page then take domain and make CNAME record for livejournal.com.
It gives you direct link to your own domain from livejournal pages but search engines didn't understaning that your domain name is primary for your blog. Also all links from your domain follows back to livejournal. Also you still can't change source of your pages dynamically.
Simplest way to do this is to don't make the CNAME record and simply attach domain to hosting and make little .htaccess editions and make index.php file that gets contents from your lj-blog and render from your domain. Editions in .htaccess makes all links working inside your own domain. BUT you can't get direct links from lj-pages this way :(

**What advice can you give me to do right redirection but working links inside domain and source code rendering. Simply to follow LJ recommendations plus my alternative way with .htaccess and index.php and other things?**

Comment: Um... a DNS request is submitted to one or more nameservers. I'm pretty sure you cannot interject your own response to a conversation to which you are not a party.

Comment: please, check my post again. It's updated.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for ["Split-horizon DNS"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-horizon_DNS).

Whether it is supported, and how to configure it, depends on the details of your DNS servers software.

Comment: Thanks for your link. I'm reding this now. But please, check my post again. It's updated.